# ¿Porque genexus esta cargando mal una variable colección?

Tags: genexus, colecciones, bug

Presento lo siguiente, en genexus tengo una variable coleccion del tipo ProveedorId, esta coleccion se carga bien con IDs pequeñas pero cuando comienza a cargar Ids muy grandes termina por cargar un numero erróneo.
Ejemplo:

```
For each
    where atributo = condicion
    &Coleccion.Add(ProveedorId)
    msg("id Proveedor:"+ProveedorId.ToString())
    msg("item que se cargo en la coleccion:"+&Coleccion.ToJson())
Endfor
```

Este código devuelve lo siguiente:

id Proveedor: 1
item que se cargo en la coleccion:["1"]

id Proveedor: 1
item que se cargo en la coleccion:["1","1"]

id Proveedor: 2222
item que se cargo en la coleccion:["1","1","9"]

id Proveedor: 3333
item que se cargo en la coleccion:["1","1","9","-44"]

De "2222" se guardo como un "9" y de "3333" se guardo como un "-44". No tiene mucho sentido. Ayuda por favor.